# Use ReferenceInput, it shows blank

Tags: admin-on-rest

When I use ReferenceInput, it shows blank with no error in the chrome console.

Below is my code. Your help, thanks.

in App.js

```
<Admin >
    <Resource name="ps" list={ConnectList} create={ConnectCreate} />
    <Resource name="schema" list={SchemaList} />
</Admin >
```

in ps.js

```
export const ConnectCreate = (props) => (
<Create title="Create New Connect Task Guide" {...props}>
    <TabbedForm>
        <FormTab label="Overview">
            <ReferenceInput label="browse topics" source="id" reference="schema" >
                   <SelectInput optionText="subject" />
            </ReferenceInput>
        </FormTab>
    </TabbedForm>        
    </Create>
);
```

schema json is as follows. I can see it successfully returned from browser network. However, the UI shows nothing.

```
[{"id":"1", "subject":"test_value"},{"id":"2", "subject":"test_value2"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

added allowEmpty, it works. Thanks guys anyway.

Comment: Why allowEmpty solved it? how it is related to the blank input?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about the `source` value (`id`) ? It should be the `schema` identifier from the `ps` resource, probably something like `schemaId`.

Comment: there is no such column in the ps resource. I'll try to get one.

Comment: update use below. but still balnk. <ReferenceInput label="browse topics" source="schemaId" reference="schema" >
                   <SelectInput optionText="subject" />
            </ReferenceInput>

Comment: Does ps and schema have to have fk relation? I want to assign them such relation through ReferenceInput. I think this is different from the usage of ReferenceField.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your use case. `ReferenceField` and `ReferenceInput` are both meant to be used for referenced fields (fk relationship).